# Unable to Uninstall a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am trying to uninstall a older version of windows service in my machine and install a latest version. But when I uninstall using `InstallUtil.exe /u` command,I got following exception "The uninstall has completed.
An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete."

After this when I try to install to the latest version, I got this exception "An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service has been marked for deletion".

I even tried to delete the service with `SC delete` command. I get "The specified service has been marked for deletion" exception again. I also tried to delete the service manually from REGEDIT. But still couldn't install the service...
I even tried to restart the machine.
can someone help me with this???

Comment: Restart........

Comment: make sure the service process is not running... also restarting might help

Comment: @Shyju Forgot to mention... I even tried it...

Comment: @NicoRiff Yes, the service is stopped..

Answer (score 0):

I did face this issue, I followed the below steps, hope they work for you.

1. Restart the system.
2. In services.msc, stop the service and set it to disabled.
3. Restart the system, boot in safe mode and uninstall the service.